# how to rotate the multicategory axis in plotly?

Tags: python, plotly

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
    x = [['First', 'First', 'Second', 'Second'],
    ["A", "B", "A", "B"]],
    y = [2, 3, 1, 5],
    name = "Adults",
))

fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
    x = [['First', 'First', 'Second', 'Second'],
    ["A", "B", "A", "B"]],
    y = [8, 3, 6, 5],
    name = "Children",
))

fig.update_layout(title_text="Multi-category axis")

fig.show()
```

**my desired output is to rotate the plot's 'first' and 'second' category to 45 degree**

[rotate the bottom category axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YZDm.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python plotly - rotating secondary X axis labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70942603/python-plotly-rotating-secondary-x-axis-labels)

Comment: agreed with comments from @Phoenix there is no direct way to control it.  work around with annotations is reasonable

Comment: @Phoenix  I have tried the suggested code. The method mentioned by the link does not solve the problem actually, because when we want to zoom in the chart, the 'manipulated' annotation just don't align.

Answer (score 0):

I used two methods to prevent category text overflow desired space when the category text is too long:

1. use smaller font size: adjust the tickfont param of the update_xaxes call

   fig.update_xaxes(tickangle=45, tickfont=dict(size=8), dividerwidth=2)
2. use 
    in the category text: if dataframe is used for instance,

   df = df.rename(columns=lambda x: (x[:truncate_len] + '
   ' + x[truncate_len:]) if (len(x) > truncate_len) else x)

truncate_len is the desired text space