# plotly and dash: double x axis both label vertically

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I'm struggling with the following problem:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "tick": ['VEEERY LOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOONG TEEEEXT', 'VEEERY LOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOONG TEEEEXT', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2'],
    "value": [12, -6, 9, -14, -10, 9, -10, 5],
    "category": ['Born', 'Died', 'Born', 'Died', 'Died', 'Born', 'Died', 'Born'],
    "type": ["Penguin", "Lion", "Penguin", "Lion", "Apes", "Penguin", "Lion", "Apes"]
})
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

# set figure twith multiple y axes
fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])
for t in df.type.unique():
    plot_df = df[df.type == t]
    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
        x=[plot_df.tick, plot_df.category],
        y=abs(plot_df.value),
        name=t,
    ))
total_df = df.groupby(['tick']).sum()

fig.update_layout({
    'barmode': 'stack',
    'xaxis': {
        'title_text': "Tick",
        'dtick': 'M1',
        'tickformat': "%m.%Y",
        'tickangle': -90,
    },
    'yaxis': {
        'title_text': "Value",
    },
})
fig.show()
```

Of course, this example is only illustrative.
But my problem is: I'd like to tick labels, like 'VEEERY LOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOONG TEEEEXT' to be displayed vertically.

However, it's not possible to do so, as
fig.update_layout's xaxis' 'tickangle' relates ONLY to the first layer(plot_df.tick) of 'x=' of fig.add_trace:

```
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
        x=[plot_df.tick, plot_df.category],
        y=abs(plot_df.value),
        name=t,
    ))
```

But I have two x's:

```
x=[plot_df.tick, plot_df.category]
```

So how can I rotate plot_df.category to be vertical, while keeping plot_df.tick vertical as well?

Comment: Your solution is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/70943609/16733101

Comment: yep. It worked for me! Although, I had to make some enhancements: play with margin, tickangle and yshift. But it worked!